# How do I read text from a file with lines that change?

Tags: bash, sed

I have this file with questions and possible answers.

```
1.- question number 1
a) option number a1
b) option number b1
c) option number c1
d) option 
number d1
2.- question number 2
a) option number a2      b) option number b2
c) option number c2      d) option number d2
```

I made this to read the questions and answers and it works well if there is only one question in the file and each option is in a single line. If there are several questions in the file, the options are in the same line or the options are bigger than one line, it does not work correctly.

```
for question in 1. 2.
do 
q=$(sed -n -e "/^$question/p" "file")
a=$(sed -n -e "/^a)/p" "file")
b=$(sed -n -e "/^b)/p" "file")
c=$(sed -n -e "/^c)/p" "file")
d=$(sed -n -e "/^d)/p" "file")
...
done
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: You certainly don't use `sed` to extract a single line at a time. Use a language with better support for reading from a file one line at a time and data structures to store what you read.

Comment: I would simply read sequentially through the file and build up an array of question and their options, so this works with any number of question and any number of options. So you have to think of : (1) How exactly should the data structure look like, which will have the questions and options stored? (2) How to extract the relevant information from a line being read? and maybe (although this is trivial): (3) How does one read a file sequentially?

Comment: Of course this makes me wonder why you want to use bash for this type of problem, since bash is not particularily suitable in the modelling of data structures.

Comment: What language would you recommend? I'm a newbie programming

Comment: You need to parse the input.  If you want the input to be flexible (eg, you allow multiple responses on a single line instead of requiring that the input be formatted with one response per line), then it is much more difficult.  If you are defining the input format, then you will have to implement the parser.

Comment: Also, that the parsing problem might be ambiguous if you have answers like "How many cakes do I eat today? a) The answer is 5. b) ..." or if any question or answer contains brackets like "1. What is my real name? (it's not kaiya)" ... and so on. So the firstmost question would be: Where do your questions come from? Do you have control over their structure? If yes, it's simple to structure them in a way that you can use bash to properly read them. If not, you really need a manual parser and even then your problem does not sound all too machine-readable :-/